# how to disable tableview specific row but the specific row contain uibutton. button must access

Tags: iphone, uitableview, avaudioplayer, xcode4.6

I have UITableview

uitableview containe playlist audio song and i put a button in cell.

User click on the row audio start to play

i want , when user click on row only button should be enable while cell should be disable

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:soundsPath];

    NSURL *  playurl =[NSURL URLWithString:[passarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] relativeToURL:url];

    if (indexPath.row ==1) {

        buybtn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        buybtn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
  }
       player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playurl error:nil]; 

        [self.player play];
        player.delegate = self;
   cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

       cellText = cell.textLabel.text;

    lbl.text=cellText;
     }
```

Comment: you want to give action for cell or button?

Comment: @sunny thank for rply 
button working bt my question is when i click on cell then audio start to play that things i don't want

Comment: you want to play audio when click on button am i correct?

Comment: i used button for buyaudio not for play audio

Answer (score 0):

This might help: Add these code in `UITableView's` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

Add `tag` to `specific` `button` say `99` then

```
for(UIView *subview in cell.subView)
{
   if(![subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]) 
   {
      subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
   }
   else
   {
      UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subview;
      if(btn.tag != 99)
        btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
   }
}
```

**EDIT** :  A `specific` `button` to be `enabled` from `other` `buttons`.

Comment: If there will be two buttons added in cell then both will be enabled. But he need a specific button to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

assign a tag to that button which you need to access as : `buybtn.tag = YOUR_TAG`

and then in didselectrow method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"sunviews  : %@",cell.subviews);
    for (UIView *_view in cell.subviews) {
        if (_view.tag != YOUR_TAG) {
            [_view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i want to disable to cell and cell container "button" that button be accessible
:(

Answer (score 0):

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
if(indexPath.row == sepicificRowNumber){

buybtn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
if(indexPath.row == sepicificRowNumber){

//Nothing happen on click   

}
```

}

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank for rply button working bt my question is when i click on cell then audio start to play that things i don't want

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; i try before bt its not work its just cell click selection style  remove blue color when user click on cell

Comment: Have you tried this: `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if(indexPath.row == sepicificRowNumber){

//Nothing happen on click   

}

}`   This will definately help.